# Visual Studio 2017 Reference Manager is empty

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to add a reference to System.Configuration assembly in Visual Studio 2017 Community edition. I'm targeting .net 4.5 version and .net classic. However, I can't find any assemblies in reference manager.

Am I missing something here? Where are the standard framework assemblies? Is it normal that Framework tab is empty?

[image]

Comment: @HansPassant My project is a "Class Library (.NET Framework)" using .net 4.5, which after project creation becomes named 1.4. I don't get what you mean..

Comment: Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence, I don't see any.  There are too many Class Library projects to choose from and the names resemble each other too much, so miss-clicking is far too easy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Targeting .NETStandard 1.4

That is not ".net classic", you picked a new project template that is available since VS2017.  .NETStandard is pretty similar to PCL of old, it helps you create a portable class library that is usable on multiple platforms.  An improvement over PCL, you no longer have to select which specific platforms you want to support.  Being "standard", all framework assemblies you *could* pick are already included, that's why the list is empty.  PCL worked the same way.

Beware that there are a lot of Class Library project templates around and choosing the wrong one is easy to do.  You'll have to pick the one named "Class Library (.NET Framework)", that's the one that targets the classic desktop version and gives you a non-empty list to choose from.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I'm sure I have picked .Net Standard instead of Net Core. This is what I choose for project creation: http://imgur.com/XibXg3R

Comment: Right, that is wrong.  Note how the template name does **not** resemble "Class Library (.NET Framework)".  .NETStandard is a very different animal, with a lousy non-descriptive name and too many standards to choose from, it replaces PCL.

Comment: In fact, you can see in my question's image that in the left upper corner of reference manager it says "targeting .Net Standard 1.4

Comment: How can I target .Net classic in VS2107?

Comment: Select the "Windows classic desktop" node.  "Classic", just what you were looking for.  Click around some more, get the lay of the land.

Comment: Ok, I got what you mean. There is a an option to add projects for .Net Core, .Net Standard and Windows Classic Desktop. A really messy naming convention :-(

Answer (score 7):

I overlooked this being a .NET Framework targeted project rather than a .NET CORE

Please see below assembly location.

[image: .NET Framework]

Comment: And how does this personal opinion help the OP in solving his issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for posting an answer. Please read the info about [how to ask a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't find any other reference but yours to the difference between .NET Framework and .NET Core Console apps.

Setting the project as "Console App .NET Framework" makes visible "Assemblies" in the "Reference manager". As a ".NET Core" App you can't add assemblies in the reference manager.