# Reference manager is empty in vs 2017 .net core class library project

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, configurationmanager

I'm trying to add reference to `System.Configuration.dll` assembly.
I'm using .Net Core, as it can be seen in my `.csproj` file:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
```

(Output type of my project is set to `Class Library`.)

To do this, in solution explorer, I right-click on `Dependencies` of my project and then click on `Add Reference...`. Problem is that the opened Reference Manager is empty and there is no assembly I can add a reference to.

However, without referencing that assembly I'm able to write the following line without any build error:

```
using System.Configuration;
```

**First Question:**  How is it possible that the above line gets successfully built, without me referencing that assembly?

If I try to use `ConfigurationManager` class to read data from app.config file (As told [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=netframework-4.7.2) ), I get an error complaining that:

```
CS0103  The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context
```

**Question two:** what can I do to solve that error? what's wrong with my code or project?

My case is not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218091/visual-studio-2017-reference-manager-is-empty) and this is not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Add Reference` is for your local references. You need to use **Nuget Package Manager** in order to include references.

most importantly .Net Core does not use .Net Framework packages where `ConfigurationManager` is .Net Framework package.

You need to use **.Net Core** or **.Net Standard** libraries with **.Net Core**